# Refetch Values or Tote Them Around

Tags: python, function, parameters

My programs are growing larger and more sophisticated. As a result I am using more and more functions. My question is, should I "fetch" a value from a function once and then "tote" it around, sending it into other functions as a parameter, or just call, "fetch," the value again from within the other function(s)?

I am sure resources, and speed, are a factor, but what is the general rule, if any?

For example, should I call my sigmoid function, and then use that value as a parameter in a call to the next function that uses it, or just call the sigmoid function again from within that next function?

I know that this question borders on opinion, but I did not attend a CS school, and so find myself wondering what the "norm" for some things are.

Thanks.

Comment: // , Have you considered taking on a formal or informal apprenticeship, @JayJay123? To use a TV analogy, many are the Frankensteins in need of an Igor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this question relates more to software engineering theory than just a language (Python). There are programming paradigms which promote one variant over the other but the most general rule of thumb you should aim for is:

> High [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and low [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)

i.e., within a *module* of software (which roughly corresponds to a Python `module`, if you are using them), the functions should have dependence on each other and you should call them to `fetch` the value. However, across modules, you should *not* have functional calls and should tie them up at a higher level module (or the `main` function) by `fetching` values from one module and passing it to the other.

See also: [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: Great answer, and just what I was looking for--a general answer/guide with clues for my further research. Much thanks.